# How to fine-tune hyphenation for mix of math and text

Tags: hyphenation

In maths texts it is common to introduce special terminology which follows the scheme

```
$math$-word
```

An example: `$\alpha$-conversion`, `$k$-clique`.

Now the first problem one encounters when using this pattern is that the `word` is not recognised by the hyphenation algorithm anymore.
A simple fix is to insert a 0-length space before the word:

```
$math$-\hskip0pt word
```

With this trick the hyphenation patterns for `word` are used correctly again.

The problem is that I would like to avoid the following line breaks:

```
$math$-
lengthyword

$math$
-lengthyword
```

and only allow hyphenation in `lengthyword`

```
$math$-len-
gthyword
```

I tried with `$math$\nobreak-\nobreak\hskip0pt word` to no avail.
What is the correct way to instruct the hyphenation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing the hyphen in an `\mbox` will preclude its use as a breakpoint.

EDIT: Thanks to barbara for providing the magic incantation to avoid the need to manually hyphenate the word following the `$math$\mbox{-}`.  In particular, a strategically placed `\nobreak`, allong with the `\hspace{0pt}` provides the generalization: `$math$\mbox{-}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}lengthyword`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth1pt
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\mbox{Not this:}
$math$-\hspace{0pt}lengthyword

\mbox{But this:}
$math$\mbox{-}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}lengthyword
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a hybrid of this and the original use of `\nobreak` allows the word following the hyphen to be hyphenated automatically: `$math$\mbox{-}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}lengthyword`.  then, don't need to be bothered with `\-`s.

Answer (score 9):

there's actually an existing command in `amsmath` for this: `\nobreakdash`.  it's
documented on p.12 of the manual (`texdoc amsmath`).

for convenience, here's a scan of the relevant section.

[image]

Comment: Very nice!!!  Touche!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- i guess i knew it was there, but the details escaped me.  the topic comes up so often of how to permit automatic hyphenation of a word after a hyphen, usually not preceded by math, that i just go for the "raw" code.  there's no reason, of course, that this couldn't be used in that situation as well, although i'm somewhat embarrassed at the one-letter control-sequence suggestions.  (i didn't write that.)

Comment: This is very useful thanks! I would still keep the current accepted answer because it does not depend on amsmath even though...who does not use it? :)

Answer (score 4):

With UTF8 input there is `‑` (U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN). I also show that U+2013 EN DASH doesn't allow a break

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}% force hyphenation everywhere possible
$p$\nobreakdash-dimensional
$p$‑dimensional % non breaking hyphen
1\nobreakdash--9
1–9 % en-dash
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to change the definition for U+2011 to allow hyphenation in the following word:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{‑}{\mbox{-}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}% force hyphenation everywhere possible
$p$\nobreakdash-dimensional
$p$‑dimensional % non breaking hyphen
1\nobreakdash--9
1–9 % en-dash
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to extend this to "normal" characters, i.e. characters that do *not* fulfill the requirement "Only characters above U+007F may be defined"?

Comment: @marmot Nothing prevents you from making `p` active, but then don’t be upset if you can’t `\hspace` any longer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. This would be too great a price to pay.