# Unsightly space in math prefix

Tags: math-mode, spacing, inline

Up until now, I've been formatting the phrase "C*-algebras" in TeX using

```
$C^*$-algebras
```

but this leaves an unsightly space between the star(*) and the hyphen (I suppose because of the switch from math mode?).

Is there a standard way of typesetting such mathematical "prefixes"?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please provide a full minimal example. I see no space issues from just adding this to a naïve doc. And our researchers who deals with $C^*$ stuff write it just this that.

Comment: Do you prefer `\newcommand\Calgebra{\textit{C}\textsuperscript{*}-algebra}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the space but I'm not sure it's an improvement:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

 $C^*$-algebras

 $C^*\!$-algebras

\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree with your assessment (that it may not be an improvement). If the OP wants, they can try something like `$C^*$\kern-.07em-algebras` which will allow them to tweak the spacing until it looks exactly how they want it to. This may lead one to insanity.

Comment: Why not include the negative space in the superscript -- `$C^{*\!}$-algebras`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton well that gives a smaller negative space, it just depends which you prefer I suppose

Comment: You might consider coding this with `\nobreakdash` because a line break really isn't wanted between `$C*$-` and `algebras`.  (requires `amsmath`)

Comment: @barbarabeeton well it's like x-ray if it was a choice of breaking somewhere, or going overfull and sticking in the margin, breaking after C*- wouldn't be so bad would it?

Comment: More often than not, in my experience at AMS, shifting something relatively short like `$C*$-` to the next line (which is what usually happens when "unbreaking" the expression) works pretty well.  (Not always, of course, but I think the possibility is worth mentioning.)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is always the simplest.  In this case, a kern to tighten it up just enough:

$C^*$\kern-1pt-algebras

I wouldn't use any skip such as \! here, as that strikes me as a botch.  Similarly, pt is the right unit to be using here.

The extra space is due to TeX enclosing C^* in a box without any information as to its visual shape.  That's just how TeX rolls, no matter whether it is setting mathematics or text.

As regards macros, I'd probably write \Cstar-algebras or \Cstar algebras:

\def\pinch{\kern-1pt}
\def\Cstar{$C^*$\pinch-}

I would never write "algebras" into a macro, instead writing that after a macro for the rest.

These solutions are adapted from the TeXbook.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Regarding the ability for the word after the hyphen to break somewhere else, see [How to fine-tune hyphenation for mix of math and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348410)

Comment: I've removed my comments surrounding this as they were incorrect and their result unacceptable.